# Loop an MySQL query in PHP with DBH

Tags: php, mysql

everbody.

I have a array I want to store in my database. Each element in each row. So I created a loop with a query using DBH. As normal queries (with no loop) go though with no problem, the query in the loop does not work. How should I correct my code?

```
for($i=0;$i<$count($array);$i++)
 {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:value1, :value2)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':value1', $value1[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':value2', $value2[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
 }
```

Even this variant doesnt work

```
for($i=0;$i<$count($array);$i++)
 {
    $stmt[$i] = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:value1, :value2)");
    $stmt[$i]->bindValue(':value1', $value1[$i]);
    $stmt[$i]->bindValue(':value2', $value2[$i]);
    $stmt[$i]->execute();
 }
```

Comment: Because your array name is not $value1 or $value2. It is **$array**

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by building the query in one loop and executing it outside the loop

```
$query = "";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
  {
     $query .= "INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('".$velue1[$i]."', '".$value2[$i]."'); ";
  }

rtrim($query, "; ");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```